# How to customize validation messages in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify in two of my applications. In the first one, we used aws-amplify v3.0.23 without Amplify-UI. It shows the following error message if username contains a space:

> Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+

However, in my other application, where we are using aws-amplify/ui-react v1.2.4 with aws-amplify v4.1.2, it shows a more user-friendly message in the same case:

> Username cannot contain whitespace

Right now, I am trying to upgrade to the latest versions of aws-amplify and aws-amplify/ui-react i.e., v4.3.15  and v2.8.0 respectively because Amplify-ui v1.2.4 does not support password managers like Last Pass.
But, I see that the latest version again shows the message "*Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+*" instead of the user-friendly message "*Username cannot contain whitespace*" in case username contains a space.
Is there any way in AWS Amplify or AWS Cognito to override the validation messages?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution! As replied by an Amplify-UI expert to my question [here](https://discord.com/channels/705853757799399426/708383821401161738/951523227325304832)
we were able to translate the error message returned by AWS Cognito to any custom message of our choice using Amplify internationalization library documented at https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator#internationalization-i18n.

Here is the code:

```
import { I18n } from 'aws-amplify';
import { translations } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
I18n.putVocabularies(translations);

const originalMessage="1 validation error detected: Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+";
const translatedMessage="Username cannot have whitespace.";

I18n.putVocabularies({
  en: {
    [originalMessage]: [translatedMessage]
  }
});
```